# how to require libraries using Docpad Sass

Tags: ruby, sass, rubygems, require, docpad

I have been following the instructions here:
[docpad-plugin-sass](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-sass)

And I have search all over for the answer even found someone requireing susy but their problem was with needing to update susy.

Unfortunately I just can't seem to get the requireLibaries to work. I have tried multiple instulations, reinstalled singularitygs but just no luck. No matter what I require I always get the same error:

> error: Something went wrong with the action
>   error: An error occured: 
>   Error: LoadError: cannot load such file -- singularitygs

This is my setup:

```
plugins:
        sass:
            compass: "true"
            requireLibraries: ['singularitygs']
            outputStyle: 'expanded'
```

I was wondering if maybe Docpad is unable to access my gems folder.

Does anyone where I am going wrong or how I can fix this?

Edit:

Wasn't sure if this would help as the problem may have to do with how I have setup my gems:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-02-24 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/Damien/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/Damien/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/Damien/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/Damien/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0
     - /Users/Damien/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: Did you install the gem with sudo ? What `docpad -v`returns ?

Comment: I have tried using both sudo and without normally with my setup with out works and I can use require in guard. this is what docpad -v returns: '$ docpad -v

  error: unknown option `-v'
'